# adjective for something bad that one did not deserve

Tags: single-word-requests

I need an adjective to qualify something bad that one gets but one did not deserve.
It's used as following

"One single action of hers had freed her from the chains of [adjective] ignominy"

I can think of misplaced, ill begotten, unearned, but none quite fit the bill here

Comment: where will your adjective be placed in the sentence? instead of "single"?

Comment: sorry. I wrote it there in angular brackets, but turns out the HTML ate it up. See my edit now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to combine the two concepts in one, **undue** would be a candidate as meaning *unwarranted or inappropriate because excessive or disproportionate*. The *disproportionate* part (most often) implies something bad, although you could imagine talking of *undue happiness*, but only for someone who is so bad he doesn't deserve it, so still some negativity there.

Otherwise you would have to combine two adjectives such as *needless*, *undeserved*, etc

Comment: I think unwarranted is good.

Answer (score 4):

**Undeserved** is the obvious choice to me.

**Unjust** or **unfair** place the situation more starkly as a matter of justice or fairness. As noted in another reply, **undue** or **unwarranted** captures better the sense of a disproportion, i.e. she deserved some ignominy but not *this* much. **Needless** or **unnecessary** can also express excess, but also that the ignominy is unfortunate because it was avoidable. **Groundless** ignominy establishes her complete innocence.